# Class variables Vs Static variables

Tags: c#

Please consider this code segment

```
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     string variable1;
     static string variable2;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      foo(); 
     }

     protected void foo()
     {
      // Can access variable1 and variable2
     }
 }
```

Couple of questions:

a) I understand that variable2 is called a class variable since it is defined as static. But what kind of variable is variable1?

b) I understand that value assigned to variable2 in a method say foo() will persist across all the methods defined in this class. But it wont in case of variable1. So my question is in what situations would we define a non-static variable in class?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You should really be looking at an intro to C# book or some tutorials on the subject to understand these basic concepts.  SO is not a replacement for that.

Comment: BTW: your item b) is just plain wrong, and likely the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time you want to avoid using static vars and methods. Static vars are accessible across all *instances* of the class and opposite of the "regular" vars that are accessible only withing the current instance. You need to be very careful when using static vars since different instances could be accessing them at the same time. Also most of the OO concepts don't translate very well to static vars.

Comment: Zdravko - So in ASP.NET environment, is it fair to say that we should not use static variables since everytime there is a postback, a new instance of page is created and would lose values of any non-static variables?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `static` methods and they are a common pattern throughout the .net framework.

Comment: @bluepiranha No. Static variables are *not* tied to instances (i.e. Pages). However, in ASP.NET one should avoid static variables, or at least realize they are a bad way to maintain state, because it might not be the same App Domain (or even process) which handles subsequent requests.

Comment: @andleer This answer does *not* claim that there is something "wrong", but rather it suggestions "avoiding [the use of] static vars", which I agree with. Pure static methods are a little bit more gray as there is no/less shared mutable state issues, but I recommend using DI/IoC to obtain the same "no-instance design" concept in an end-application. Something as simple as `DateTime.Now` shows how static accessors can be "wrong" when doing integration testing (I don't use `DateTime.Now` directly in my codebase for this exact reason).

Comment: @adler - all I said was that unless you are really sure you want to use static, you should not make your vars or methods static. obviously there are numerous cases when static is what you need and what you should do. for beginner, if you do not understand the consequences - avoid...

Comment: people tend to overuse `static`. tools like resharper even suggest you make a method static. is is all wrong, they should suggest to make it `virtual` so someone can inherit your class and override a method to modify the behavior. so let's not start a religious war and please do not downvote my answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, variable1 is an instance variable. Below is a simple example. Keep in mind it's **not good practice** to do this, but just to illustrate the point:

```
public class Person
{
    public static string Species { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetSpecies()
    {
        return Species;
    }
}
```

Consider the use... We can have 2 separate `Person` objects, each with a unique name, but they share the same species because it is "static":

```
Person.Species = "Homo Sapien";

Person alice = new Person();
aline.Name = "Alice";

Person bob = new Person();
bob.Name = "Bob";

Console.WriteLine(alice.Name);
Console.WriteLine(alice.GetSpecies());
// Alice
// Homo Sapien

Console.WriteLine(bob.Name);
Console.WriteLine(bob.GetSpecies());
// Bob
// Homo Sapien
```

If we were to change `Person.Species = "Dog"` then both Bob and Alice would have "Dog" as their species, but their names will still be "Bob" and "Alice".

Answer (score 0):

I think that the static variable `variable2` is transversal to all the instances of the class, while  `variable1` is accessible only by the single class instance. In other words the static variable is shared with all the instances.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields are shared across all instances of the same class, which in a web environment includes multiples threads across multiple users and thus should not be used. Static methods are fine in a web environment as long as they avoid static fields.